# How do I edit a specific line in a text file with python without converting everything in the text file into a list?

Tags: python

Im creating a code that has six quizzes and all the results from these quizzes get stored in the users text file (code below is from a larger piece of code).

This code below is from one of the quizzes and shows how the results get stored in the file (the 'Counter' variable is the results):

```
User = str(input("please re-enter your username: "))
    with open(User+'.txt', 'r') as f:
        line = f.readlines()
        line[8] = Counter

    with open('User+.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(str(line))
```

Depending on the quiz, one of the '-' in the user's file should change to the score for that quiz (EG: if I scored 1 on a quiz, the user's file should show this):

```
(username)
(password)
(year)
(firstname)
(surname)
-
-
-
1
-
-
```

However when its run, the user's file converts into this:

```
['(username)\n', '(password)\n', '(year)\n', '(firstname)\n', '(surname)\n', '-\n', '-\n', '-\n', 1, '-\n', '-']
```

What do I have to change in the code in order for my results to be shown like that?

Comment: Just don't convert `line` to a string. This will make the list into the one-line string you read in the file. Just do  `f.writelines(line)`

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `writelines()` is supposed to be a list of strings. That's what `line` is, you don't need to call `str()`. So the last line should be:

```
f.writelines(line)
```

If `Counter` contains an integer, you need to convert it to a string when putting it into `line[8]`:

```
line[8] = str(Counter)
```

Comment: I've tried that already but it just shows me this error on f.writelines(line): TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Comment: `line[8] = str(Counter)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. Though I do have another problem i'll just make another question